# Joomla calendar form field read only

Tags: xml, joomla, form-fields

I created joomla module and added calendar form field.

```
<field name="date" type="calendar" default="2010-01-30" format="%Y-%m-%d" label="Enter date" description="" class="date_field" />
```

Everything works fine while user uses calendar icon to input date, but if user writes any other info, than after saving module settings everything crashes.

My idea is to make input field read only, but if i use readonly="true", than callendar icon disappear.

Comment: Why would you need to calendar button if it is read only? If you want a decorative image of a calendar add it using css.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need to do some mootools or jquery-magick (depending on your joomla-version) to disable manual input in the textbox. Using jquery you could do something like:

```
jQuery('.calendar-textfield-class').focusin(function (event){
event.preventDefault(); 
jQuery(this).next('button').focus().click(); 
});
```

This should trigger the calendar select popup if the user tries to input the date manually.

Regards Jonas

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(document).on('keydown', '#jform_scheduled_time', function(event) {
       return false;
    });
});

Try this and user will not able to write anything in calendar box and for opening calendar pop up on click anywhere do this-

jQuery(document).on('focusin', '#jform_scheduled_time', function(event) {
           event.preventDefault();
           jQuery(this).parent().siblings(':eq(0)').show();
    });
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing information on how and why it solves the problem improves its long-term value.

Comment: At first joomla doesnt disable the calendars input box, So when users enters text in the calendars input box it saves some wrong values. To prevent this we can use the keydown event on calendar element and prevent user from entering anything by returning false.